# Use awk to replace start and end of each line in a large file

Tags: regex, linux, awk, gawk

I have a series of large (25-250MB) tab delimited text files I need to convert for bulk insert into SQL format. I'm extremely new to awk, so I have no idea what I am doing. All I know is I need the solution to process the data in as little time as possible. As a result, my attempts have been feeble. I have tried to achieve the following my making three separate passes at each file with sed (total cluster) and awk; like so...

Pass 1: `awk '{gsub(/%J\t/,"\(\'")}1' file.txt`

Pass 2: `awk '{gsub(/\n,"\'\)\n")}1' file.txt`

Pass 3: `awk '{gsub(/\t/,"\',\'")}1' file.txt`

Due to my severe lack of experience with awk, when I try the above, the terminal shifts to a new prompt like it's waiting for more information instead of executing the commands.

Here is a sample of how the data is formatted throughout the file.

Each line is structured like this:

%J\t**DATA**\t**DATA**\t**DATA**\t**DATA**\t**DATA**\n

I would like to use awk or something as fast to restructure each line to the following format:

```
('DATA','DATA','DATA','DATA','DATA',@id)\n
```

NOTE: I apologize if I don't have the formatting quite right. This is my very first post on Stack.

Thank you all in advance for your time and help with this one!

Comment: show your attempt

Comment: Please post 3 simple things, 1- Sample Input in CODE TAGS, 2- Sample Output in CODE TAGS, 3- your conditions and your attempt in your post.

Comment: What is `@id`? If you are going to make terminology a definition for it would be welcome. Your attempts are failing because you have single quotes inside single quotes.

Comment: Hi JNevill, the @id is litteral. What I am trying to construct is a set of MySQL BULK INSERTs. I've got the single quotes escaped. Does that not work for awk?

Comment: The shell interprets the quotes before Awk even runs. You cannot escape single quotes within single quotes in the Bourne shell (though some other workarounds are possible).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
awk -F"\t" -v q="'" '{printf "("}{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf "%s\t", q $i q}}{print "@id)"}'
```

This says:

1. Split each record by a tab `-F"\t"`
2. Set variable `q` to a single quote: `-v q="'"`
3. Print out a starting parentheses `'{printf "("}`
4. Loop through each column in the record starting at column 2 `for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)`
5. Print the column followed by a tab surrounding the column in single quotes (using the variable): `printf "%s\t", q $i q`
6. Finally print out the literal `@id` followed by a closing parentheses using the `print` command so it pops out a carriage return at the end of the print: `print NR")"`

```
:~> cat testfile
%J      D1      D2      D3
%J      D2      D3      D4
:~> awk -F"\t" -v q="'" '{printf "("}{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf "%s\t", q $i q}}{print "@id)"}' testfile
('D1'   'D2'    'D3'    @id)
('D2'   'D3'    'D4'    @id)
```

Comment: Thank you, JNevill! Thank you for the answer and for the generous explanation. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Glad I could help. I think this answer could be a little more succint by monkeying with the ORS and OFS variables, but this will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

with `(g)awk` options and using @JNevill's input file

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v RS='%J' -v ORS="',@id)\n" -v OFS="','" -v q="('" 'NF{$1=q $1; print}' file

('D1','D2','D3',@id)
('D2','D3','D4',@id)
```

Comment: you may have a `\r` in your data file, if coming from Windows, perhaps run `dos2unix`.

Comment: Hi karakfa, this has gotten me even closer. I am having two issues: there is a \n occurring right before the '@id) in my tests, and it's replacing spaces and tabs.

INPUT:
`%J 1381 443 3 201-GE General 7850410 Control Systems 443

My your code:
`awk -v RS='%J' -v ORS="',@id)\n" -v OFS="','" -v q="'" 'NF{$1="("q $1; print}' origin.txt > test.txt`

OUTPUT:
('1381','443','3','201-GE','General','7850410','Control','Systems','Engineering','443
',@id)

Any thoughts? I'm still crackin' at it.

Comment: Adding -F"\t" fixed the spaces being replaced.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked. First, thank you JNevill and karakfa! You both made this possible and I learned loads!!

```
INPUT
%J  1381    443 3   201-GE  General 7850410 Control Systems 443
%J  1382    443 3   201-GE  General 7850250 Mechanical  443
%J  1383    443 3   201-GE  General 7850400 Electrical  443

CODE
dos2unix test.txt // Ran this first to clean up the '\r's in the file.
awk -F"\t" -v RS='%J\t' -v ORS="',@id)\n" -v OFS="','" -v q="'" 'NF{$1="("q $1; print}' test.txt > test_.txt // Then ran this to finish the job

OUTPUT
('1381','443','3','201-GE','General','7850410','Control Systems','443',@id)
('1382','443','3','201-GE','General','7850250','Mechanical','443',@id)
('1383','443','3','201-GE','General','7850400','Electrical','443',@id)
```

Tada! Thanks again. Now I just need to do some GC and all is bueno.